# Method that waits for user's second click

Tags: java

I'm building a Chess game and I'm stuck on a method.

Once the user clicks on the piece he/she wants to move,
I then want to wait for the user to pick a destination for the selected piece.

I've already got an event handle on the  first click which selects the piece but I'm not sure of
how to handle the second click which picks the destination.

Here's my question: Is there a method that will wait for the user to click somewhere after they've already clicked the board once?

Comment: You will need to add state somewhere to record the first click and where it was. At that point, your program should operate in the 'mode' of waiting for the second click: new click events should have a different set of behavior than if you were in the virgin mode.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.  You are operating within an event driven environment.  This means, an event occurs you handle it.

What you need to do is make determinations about the current state of your application.

For example...

- The user clicks a piece.  You check to see if a piece has been selected previous, if not, you set the "selected piece" accordingly, otherwise you determine if the move is legal or not
- The user clicks a blank spot.  You check to see if the "selected piece" has been set, if it has, you determine if the move is legal or not other wise you would probably ignore it.

The process is about establishing appropriate states within your model and allowing your model to deal with requests...

For example...

*"Move piece to A4"*

- No piece selected, invalid operation
- Piece selected, but piece can't move in that manner, invalid operation
- Piece selected, grid occupied, can piece take other piece....
- etc...

Separate your game "logic" from the actual physical implementation, it will make your job significantly easier in the long run...